# Static variable in 'for' loop initial declaration

Tags: c, static, c99

Would like to know why cannot I declare a Static variable in `for` loop initialization as shown below,

```
for(static int i = 0;;)
```

Compiling the above loop statement code with my `C99` standard compiler I see the below error,

```
error: declaration of static variable ‘i’ in ‘for’ loop initial declaration
```

Comment: Because the language doesn't allow it?  In what circumstances would this be useful?

Comment: Whenever I encounter a "strange" error message like this, I like to **think** about it. At some point, it always turns out that if something is not allowed, then it's not allowed for a reason -- usually because it doesn't make sense (as in this example).

Comment: @OliCharlesworth: While I agree that this makes no sense and that the language shouldn't/doesn't allow it, I can't actually find any text in C99 that explicitly forbids this.  None of §6.2.2, §6.2.4, §6.7.1, and §6.8.5.3 mention any restrictions on the declaration of `clause-1` of the `for` loop AFAICT.

Comment: @OliCharlesworth Ah actually it's at the top of §6.8.5, I somehow missed that (thanks @Chux!)

Comment: @OliCharlesworth Inside `for` loop I have a circular ring with packet data indexed `[0, Size-1]` which should be read sequentially traversing the ring. So I've tried declaring static as my function is invoked for every packet. I know declaring it outside `for` will help me.

Comment: The question is not that much bad. +1

Comment: @haccks This is indeed a bad question.

Comment: @H2CO3; I gave it a +1 because it was new to me. :)

Comment: That declaration has only one sense. It prevents include additional code for taking and freeing memory for auto variable. sometimes usefull when we write some firmware. And we really don't know when variable is initialized, when code will run in its initialization block, or when cpu reaches this part of code.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

C does not allow it

C11dr 6.8.5 **Iteration statements** 3

"The declaration part of a `for` statement shall only declare identifiers for objects having storage class `auto` or `register`".

(not `static`)

---

Typically code would not benefit form being able to have an iterator that is `static`.

---

storage-class-specifier:

```
typedef
extern
static
_Thread_local
auto
register
```

Comment: @SunEric T'was an interesting post.  Never tried a `static` iterator before.  As per your comment above, one can readily get around it ("declaring it outside for").  I suspect that reasons to attempt using a `static` iterator may have unintended side-effects (re: re-entrantcy and others` posts), thus precluding this approach.  Good luck.

Answer (score 5):

The purpose of declaring a variable in the `for` declaration is narrowing its scope to the loop block.

```
// i does not exist here
for (int i = 0;;) {
  // i exists here
}
// i does not exist here
```

When you declare a local variable as `static` and initialize it, the initialization is done only once, when the code is first run.

```
{
  static int i = 0; // i will be set to 0 the first time this is called
  i++;
}
```

So a `for` loop with a `static` variable that is initialized in the loop declaration will only be initialized once!

```
// i will not be initialized to 0 the second time this loop runs and we cannot
// initialize it here, before the loop block
for (static int i = 0;;) {
  // ...
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Actually, this compiles and works as expected in g++ 4.4.3.

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define LOG() testPrintfPtr
#define LOG_ONCE() \
    for (static bool __only_once_ = 0; !__only_once_; __only_once_ = true) \
        LOG()

struct test {
    void debug(const char *str) {
        printf("%s\n", str);
    }
};

test *testPrintfPtr = new test();

int main() {
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
        LOG_ONCE()->debug("ciao 1");

    LOG_ONCE()->debug("ciao 2");

    return 0;
}
```

The purpose is to provide a seamless wrapper to a logging api (whose entry point is provided globally by the `LOG()` macro) so that that log line is only executed once during the program's lifetime.

Executing the program gives the following:

```
$ ./testLogOnce
ciao 1
ciao 2
```

I assume the C++ standard allows it?

Answer (score 1):

What are you trying to accomplish?

If you're trying to be able to access the variable `i` outside the `for` loop, you'll have to declare it outside the `for` loop:

```
int i;
for(i = 0; ; )
{
    …
}
printf("%d\n", i);
```

If you'd like to have the `for` loop execute only the first time a function is called, create a `static` boolean variable to handle that.

```
static bool firstTime = true;

if(firstTime)
{
    for(int i = 0; ; )
    {
        …
    }

    firstTime = false;
}
```